# Rails conditional for 2 of 3 present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using Rails 4 and have a multiform leading into a page which displays the results of a search. The multiform is 3 separate forms/models or combinations of the 3 forms. I need to write a condition in ERB to display total results if 2 or 3 of those 3 forms are completed. I have written conditionals to display detailed results from each form (see below) but now need totals. I am hoping to avoid a complicated if statement with a bunch of AND/OR statements. Any ideas? Below the embedded create page. I am looking to write the conditional after the first container div.

```
 <div class='container'>
  <% if %>

  <% end %>
</div>

<div class='container'>
  <% unless @form1.blank? %>
    <%= render "createForm1" %>
  <% end %>

  <% unless @form2.blank? %>
    <%= render "createForm2" %>
  <% end %>

  <% unless @form3.blank? %>
    <%= render "createForm3" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.count` with a block:

```
if [@form1, @form2, @form3].count(&:blank?) >= 2
```

Answer (score 0):

`filled_forms = [@form1, @form2, @form3].select(&:present?)] # will give you those forms which were filled out`

in order to now if at least 2 were filled run `filled_forms.length >= 2`

in container you may iterate over them without `unless` condition

Comment: Where would I specify the variable filled_forms? In the controller? Also, you have an extra bracket, is that necessary?

Comment: @JoeD this extra bracket is unnecessary (writing from Windows...). In general the best option is to either declare `filled_forms` in controller or some kind Presenter which you pass to view. Of course it is possible to do it even in view, but IMHO it's rather a bad practise.